# Php - Reading file lines into an array

Tags: php, html, algorithm, file

The numbers in my file are 5X5:

```
13456
23789
14789
09678
45678
```

I'm trying to put it into this form

```
array[0]{13456}
array[1]{23789}
array[2]{14789}
array[3]{09678}
array[4]{45678}
```

My code is:

```
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  //Throw an error message if the file could not be open
  $file = fopen($fileName,"r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

  while ($line = fgets($file)) {
      $digits .= trim($line);
     $members = explode("\n", str_replace(array("\r\n","\n\r","\r"),"\n",$digits));
      echo $members;
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` gets a line from the file pointer, so theoretically there should be no `"\r"` or `"\n"` characters in `$line`. `explode` will still work, even if the delimiter is not found. You'll just end up with an array with one item, the entire string. You can't echo an array, though. (That's why you're seeing `Array` for each line; it's the best PHP can do when you use `echo` on an array.)

If I were you, I would rather just use `file()` instead.

```
$members = array_map('trim', file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

With the example file you showed, this should result in

```
$members = ['13456', '23789', '14789', '09678', '45678'];
```

Comment: Should I add the line of code inside my while loop?

Comment: No, that line should replace all the code after the file name valuable is defined. No loop needed

Comment: how do I call the $member function so that the strings in the array could be integers?

Comment: You can use intval, but typically it isn't necessary. PHP will automatically convert numeric strings to numbers if they're used in numeric contexts.

Comment: sorry, but last question, but is there a way to put my results into a matrix?

Comment: No problem! If I understand correctly what you mean by matrix, you should look at the `str_split` function. You can map that over the array of lines to convert the numeric strings to arrays of digits.

Comment: Like `$members = array_map('str_split', $members)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the lines into an array and use print_r instead of echo to print that array

```
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
  $members[] = $line;
}
print_r($members);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should depend on the file that you are dealing with.

FileType:

- text -> fgets($file)
- CSV  ->  fgetcsv($file)